# Mule connection management

Tags: tomcat8, emulex

I have a mule flow that performs a sequential file transfer to a external SFTP. The flow transfers six files to remote SFTP. 
Lately we are noticing issues, these incidents appear randomly.  During few transfers we are coming across following error.

Error during login to username@HostName: Auth fail (java.io.IOException)

As per the team managing the remote SFTP, Mule is rapidly opening connections but not closing these. A solution implemented to make this work is the team has increased the SFTP connections limit from 4 to 30. I have been also recommended to add delay between transfers to allow connections to close.

I am tracing the flow on debug, but the implementation of SFTPConnector is not listing debug logs for connection states, Open or close.

I came across following post that indicates this is a known issues with Mule. 
https://github.com/mulesoft/mule-module-requester/issues/23

Has someone come across similar issue in past, if yes how did you overcome the issue.

I will be glad if someone could specify an implementable alternative to this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Comments updated, Please remove onhold on the question.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and the solution was to upgrade the runtime.